# Can / should up votes be separated from "Me too" votes

Tags: feature-request

If I'm scrolling SO looking for an answer to a question, and I find a question that is the same question I wish to ask, I tend to up vote.  Should these up votes not be separated from the "Yes, this is a good / well formed question" votes?  It seems to me that it would be more useful for ranking popular questions.

To give an illustration of my point: if I ask a question, but the question doesn't receive any attention, but then gets 5 up-votes - doesn't it make a difference if those 5 are people saying that they have exactly the same question, rather than just saying that they think I posed the question well?

EDIT

I think what I was thinking (4 years ago) was that an upvote on SO is ambiguous.  It could have several meanings - in fact, I reckon if you surveyed people that have just upvoted and asked why they had done so, you'd get about 20 different responses.  You might find the question helpful because you have the same question, or you might just think it's a well formed question, or maybe it's a question about a technology that you're learning and so that is helpful, and so on.

My point was that one of these reasons is special: I have the same question / problem as the person that asked this question.  That feels to me like useful information, both to allow people to see which questions they are answering that have many people with the same issue, but also for vendors to work out if they have an issue with a particular piece of software.

Comment: Why should there be a distinction? If you find the question helpful because you have the same question, then isn't the question helpful?

Comment: While this isn't always going to be the case, usually when you see a questions where you know the the problem is the same as yours and the answer to that question will help you, then the question *should* be well formed and clear as you understood it

Comment: It the question is as good as the one you would have asked (I assume you only post well-formed ones), it *does* deserve an upvote. If not, you might improve it.

Comment: Perhaps votes (up and down) should have an *optional* classifier ("me too", "dupe", "well/poorly written", etc.).

Comment: I've added a little to my point.  I'm not arguing that both cases don't deserve an up vote, just that it feels that it would be more useful to differentiate between questions that are very well written but apply to only one person, and questions that apply to 10 people but may not be as well written.

Comment: @dilbert [Like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6a2v2.png) Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: Maybe the UI could be slightly better than that :-)

Comment: @CodyGray, not even close. I was actually thinking of a mouse over dialog (triggered by hovering over the score) of a list of classifications. Given it's optional, you don't even need look at it if you don't want to.

Comment: I think this is a sensible feature request. SO tries to stop people adding "me too" or "+1" or "worked for me" type comments. Rather than preventing them, why not let people do it with a feature?
Upvote is not the same as "worked for me", there is not always only one answer that works. Sometimes one solution is "better" but another works more often.

Comment: I wish there was a "me too!" button for this question because I have the same question.

Comment: @pm_2: Sorry for stirring up the pot...

Comment: @CodyGray: (referring to your first comment) Maybe I get confused by the tooltip for the upvote arrow. Should it then read: "This question shows research effort **and/or** it is useful **and/or** clear?" Or perhaps just "This question is useful," period (like it does for answers)?

Comment: I've updated the post to clarify my thoughts... I still think this would be a good idea, but I do sympathise with @CodyGray in that it's an easy feature to get wrong - the last thing you want is 20 buttons next to every question, or a popup every time you vote.

Comment: @dilbert I would disagree with the inclusion of dupe in the additional classification since a well written dupe can help people find the information they need when it is closed with a target question that has the answer but may not show up in some searches due to different terms and wording used.

Answer (score 3):

There is a false premise to your analysis: that question upvotes are not already cast by a vast majority of people also having that problem or question.

I would posit that it is a very high percentage of users who upvote questions because that was either what they were going to ask, or generated the solution to the problem they were encountering.

There is no need to separate the vote counts.