# "Me too" button and auto-bounties from Community for high-quality questions without answers

Tags: feature-request

My question is very similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258151/can-should-up-votes-be-separated-from-me-too-votes), which has several comments but no answer.

I was poking around a Microsoft forum and noticed that they had a "me too!" button. My question: any chance that we can have something like this too? It seems like it would be particularly helpful to new users who can't comment yet (plus it would help reduce the number of "me too!" answers in the VLQ review queue).

My idea (and this is one thing that's distinct from the other post): if a post gets a high number of "me too!" votes and/or upvotes and there aren't any answers after a certain period of time it could have a bounty attached to it by the community. The amount of the bounty would be in proportion to the length of time it's gone unanswered and the number of upvotes and "me too!" votes it's received. This would give an added incentive to answer high-quality (but potentially more research-intensive) questions. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453656/store-kinects-v2-0-motion-to-bvh-file) from May 2015 has 247 upvotes (including from me) and 17 favorites and is protected by Community but it currently has no answers.

Comment: I don't see why you believe just upvotes are not enough? Answering (correctly) highly popular question without answers will likely bring plenty of reputation which would be hard to beat by any regular bounty. Note that question you've linked has plenty of (deleted) low quality answers - so there is no shortage of people trying...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It does seem like there are heavily upvoted answers that don't have any answers (or at least no answers that were good enough to make it out of the VLQ queue - I don't have enough reputation to see deleted answers yet though).

Comment: Why can't the "Me Too" button just be the one shaped like an upward-facing triangle? Highly-upvoted questions that aren't answered can be bountied at any time by high-rep community members seeking to make the site better for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some other problems with this:

- Sometimes bad questions end up with just up votes; it's how the site ends up with bad audits. I don't think a bad question that happened to slip through the cracks should get rewarded with a bounty.
- This potentially puts bounties on questions that are unanswerable or obsolete.
- If none of the people who up voted the question cared enough to place a bounty on it, then why should the system do it for them? Is it really fair to the users who spend their own rep to get their question seen to still have to compete with questions that just happened to go unanswered?

Answer (score 4):

I fundamentally disagree with this for a few reasons.

1. "Me too" conveys no real message.  It means that a mass of people *believe* they have the same question.  If that's the case, then we have a system that largely deals with that - duplicate closure.  If they ask a question which has an answer elsewhere, then the benefit would be that they'd get their answer.
2. I'm aware that you're concerned about questions *without* an answer, but that too is the nature of the system.  The current way to attract attention to it is for an individual to place a bounty of some amount on it.  The cost of the bounty is up to the individual; how much do they really think that question is worth to them?  Bounties aren't meant for the community in this context; they're meant for the individual.
3. [The question you've mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453656/store-kinects-v2-0-motion-to-bvh-file) actually *did* have some answers on it - 8 of 'em to be exact (at the time of writing).  The issue with them was that **every single answer** was effectively a link-only answer.  That is, the best answers that could be mustered were effectively pulled from a Google search.

Comment: Were they deleted answers? (I don't have enough reputation to see deleted answers yet).

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  Oh yeah, they're deleted.  They were link-only, so it's a *good* thing they were deleted.  But that's really besides the main point of your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with point #1 - I think that the main message that "me too" would convey is that the question may need more attention. In particular, it seems like there should be some way to make sure that new users can get help too (although I guess you could argue that it's not all that hard to get 50 reputation to be able to offer a bounty and that if you want to get more out of the community it's only fair to expect that you'd give back too). Point #2 is a good point though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  The best signal for attention on a question is a bounty.  Everything else isn't worth the time, since at that point, one *has* to entice a person to pay attention to a question in a popular tag for an answer.

Comment: I don't understand point #1. There is one unanswered question that everyone is latching on to hoping for an answer. No one is asking duplicates of that question and even if they did, there is no suitable duplicate target because the answer simply doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, that was my thinking as well... my thinking is that new users can't upvote, comment, or add a bounty when they first join, so really if someone's mostly coming on here for that one question they don't really have a mechanism to draw attention to it other than to either add an "I'm having this problem too" answer that winds up getting manually deleted in the VLQ queue or to create a new question that's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Rather than saying they believe they have the same question, I would say they believe they have the same problem basing on the symptoms. I agree that knowing other users would be interested in having an answer for that question is not something we are interested in. If there are users interested in an answer, they could put a bounty too, if they need an answer so badly.